# UWP C# Image (UI Element) Collision Detection problem

Tags: c#, uwp, 2d, collision-detection

I have 2 images moving(UI ELEMENT), a shepherd and a wolf.
I want if they are in the same area of each of the pictures (if they touch each other) something will happen(the shepherd will die).

I'm noob and I thought about a for loop but it only works after trying hard to  die... lol...

```
private void GameOver(Image enemy, Image actualToMove)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {

            if (Canvas.GetLeft(actualToMove) == (Canvas.GetLeft(enemy) - i) && Canvas.GetTop(actualToMove) == (Canvas.GetTop(enemy) - i)
                || Canvas.GetLeft(actualToMove) == (Canvas.GetLeft(enemy) + i) && Canvas.GetTop(actualToMove) == (Canvas.GetTop(enemy) + i))
            {
                gameOver = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Ithought about this loop to grab a sheep and it works... but the sheep is static.
im pretty sure a for loop in this situation is a really bad idea...

I having a real hard time to make a collision detection in UWP... Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Manipulation event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/touch-interactions#manipulation-events) to move your images. For example, You could move the image in `ManipulationDelta` event, and in the `ManipulationCompleted` event, you could make a collision detection. You did not need to use a loop.